# How to use the do-notation to write a trampoline function in continuation passing style?

Tags: haskell

Mind the following function:

```
range :: Int -> [Int]
range 0 = []
range n = (n - 1) : range (n - 1)
```

We can convert it to a trampoline CPS function:

```
data Trampoline a = Done a | Wrap (() -> Trampoline a)

call :: Trampoline a -> a
call (Done a) = a
call (Wrap f) = call (f ())

range :: Int -> [Int]
range n = call (loop n Done) where
  loop :: Int -> ([Int] -> Trampoline [Int]) -> Trampoline [Int]
  loop 0 cont = cont []
  loop n cont = loop (n - 1) (\ tail -> Wrap (\x -> cont (n - 1 : tail)))
```

But it looks particularly ugly. Is there any built-in way to write this function using the do-notation, so that it looks more or less like this?

```
range n :: Int -> CPS [Int]
range 0 = do
  return []
range n = do
  tail <- range (n - 1)
  return (n - 1 : tail)
```

Comment: @leftaroundabout oops, fixed

Comment: Your `Trampoline` type is equivalent to `Free ((->) ())`. That already has a monad instance.

Comment: @Carl interesting! But the `loop` on `range` doesn't return a `Trampoline` directly, but instead it has one extra argument that looks like the CPS monad. Not sure if applying the Trampoline monad directly is what is needed here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can use `ContT`, and as Carl pointed out in the comments, your `Trampoline` is a specialisation of `Free`, so we can reuse its `Monad` instance, or you can write the instances for your `Trampoline` yourself.

```
import Control.Monad.Cont  -- mtl
import Control.Monad.Free  -- free

call :: Free ((->) ()) a -> a
call (Pure a) = a
call (Free f) = call (f ())

type Trampoline = Free ((->) ())

range :: Int -> ContT [Int] Trampoline [Int]
range 0 = pure []
range n = do
  t <- range (n - 1)
  pure (n - 1 : t)
```

Used like so, where `pure` is the initial continuation:

```
> call (runContT (range 5) pure)
[4,3,2,1,0]
```

Basically, whenever you have a function that looks like `(a -> b) -> b` (or `(a -> m b) -> m b`), it can be wrapped up in `Cont` (resp. `ContT`). Here, that’s `([Int] -> Trampoline [Int]) -> Trampoline [Int]`, where `a` = `[Int]`, `m` = `Trampoline`, and `b` = `[Int]`.

`(->) ()` could also be replaced with `Reader ()`, or simply `Identity`, since due to laziness, `() -> a` is isomorphic to just `a`—albeit possibly with some performance differences, such as better sharing with the latter.

Furthermore, `Free` over `Identity` is basically just a list, so at least this example is just a slightly convoluted way of using `ContT` over `[]` or `NonEmpty`, where `call` is `Data.List.NonEmpty.head`—or even just a list by itself. But there may of course be valid reasons to structure code this way.

Comment: I didn't know about **streamly** either. It is way more what I need and way more than CPS.
Here's all it can do: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streamly-0.7.3/docs/Streamly-Tutorial.html
It seems it can do multiple stacks, for any purpose, easily.
Unix pipes were asynchronous.
All good things Haskell come from monads.